# python: open-cv VideoCapture not working

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I am trying to get python opencv to read and display images from the integrated camera on my Lenovo Thinkpad SL510.  It seems that the software is not detecting the camera.  The light next to the camera does **not** turn on.
I am running Ubuntu 16.04, python 2.7, and opencv 3.0.  Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('video', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(0):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Note that `ret==False and frame==None`.  I've tried the fixes from several other sites, such as a delay or if statement with the return, but that didn't work.  Like I said, I don't think it is detecting the camera.  Also I tried `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` and `VideoCapture(1)` and that doesn't help either. The error is: `cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:325: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow`

**Edit:**

so I see that the first thing to try is `python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())" | grep -i ffmpeg`
This returned `FFMPEG:                      NO`  What should I do?

Comment: Are you able to use the integrated camera using a video player like `VLC`?

Comment: how does your /dev/video look like?

Comment: @LakshyaKejriwal It works with Cheese

Comment: @Micka `crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Oct 28 21:54 /dev/video0`

Comment: you could try "sudo apt-get install qv4l2 
sudo aptitude install qv4l2 
qv4l2 /dev/video0" for a quick test

Comment: did you try starting your program with sudo?

Comment: @Micka I will try qv4l2 when I get a chance to.  Could you remind me how to run the program with sudo?  I usually run my programs within pycharm.